# Get Selected Value of html dropdown in razor page dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, razor

With the below code how can I get the value of the dropdown list using page handlers or tag helpers?

One way I've been reading is using OnChange on the dropdown, I can set the value of a hidden field with javascript then get value of hidden field from code behind. Should I even be using page handlers/tag helpers to get the dropdown value?

I have tried using `Request.Form["networks"]` but this just gives the ID and not the Value.

```
<form method="post">
     @Html.DropDownList("networks",
     Model.GetNetworks().Select(s => new SelectListItem()
     {
         Text = s.networks,
         Value = s.id.ToString(),
     }),
     new
     {
        @class = "dropdown form-control",
     })
     <input type="hidden" id="selectedwifivalue" />
     <br />
     <input type="text" placeholder="enter wifi password" asp-for="Password" class="input-sm form-control" />
     <br />           
     <button asp-page-handler="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm form-control">Submit</button>
</form>
```

### Model is

```
public class WifiNetworks
{   
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string networks { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserNetworks { get; set; }
}
```

### Code behind in cshtml file

```
[BindProperty]
public string Password { get; set; }
public string networks { get; set; }
public void OnPostSubmit()
{
    {
        var password = Request.Form["password"];
        var network = Request.Form["networks"]; <--this just gives the ID and not the value
        var wifi = networks;  <---this is blank
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the form elements value, You can use `Request.Form` collection by passing the name of the form element.Set name property of html element and check.

Below is sample code for get form element value using name property.

#### View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ReceiveValueWithRequestFormData", "ControllerAndAction"))
{
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.Label("Username")
            @Html.TextBox("txtUserName") : user
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.Label("Password")
            @Html.TextBox("txtPassword") : pass
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
}
<div id="divResult"></div>
```

#### Controller :

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ReceiveValueWithRequestFormData()
        {
            string userName = Request.Form["txtUserName"]; 
            string password = Request.Form["txtPassword"];
            if (userName.Equals("user", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            && password.Equals("pass", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return Content("Login successful !");
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Login failed !");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Request.Form doesnt work on the dropdown it keeps getting the int value and not the selected string

Answer (score 0):

In the end I could have done it using ajax but using the hidden field approach it works fine like below no idea if this is a good/bad/better way to do this (I seemed to be asking those questions quite alot)

get value of dropdown using jquery "change" function (keep this outside of the

$(document).ready function as it wont fire)

```
    $('#dnetworks').change(function () {

        var selectedwifi = $('#networks option:selected').text();

        $('#hiddenselectedwifivalue').val(selectedwifi); //set value of hidden field 

});
```

Razor page

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenselectedwifivalue" asp-for="WifiNetworks.networks" />
```

.cshtml file

```
  var selectedwififromdd = WifiNetworks.networks;
```

I used the bind for the whole class in the model page (.cshtml file)

```
  public class WifiModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty] public WifiNetworks WifiNetworks { get; set; }
```